# How to open up serial terminal for my USB device converter (or, how to enable VCP in linux)?

Tags: serial, embedded, linux, ftdi, cyclone

I am using a new Cyclone V SoC board by Enclustra ([Mercury+ SA2](https://www.enclustra.com/en/products/system-on-chip-modules/mercury-sa2/)) mounted on their [PE-1 BaseBoard](https://www.enclustra.com/en/products/base-boards/mercury-pe1-200-300-400/).

To connect to the board serially on Windows platform, I have to connect the board which is detected as `USB Serial Device Converter` in the Device Manager. And, next, from the properties, I need to **enable VCP**. By doing this, now the attached board shows up as a COM port, which enables me to access it using a serial terminal such as putty. This works correctly.

I'm trying to do the same on my Linux system running Ubuntu 16.04. The device is detected as ttyUSB0. I have already tried the `screen` statement. The `moserial` GUI. Doesn't Work. How should I proceed from here? Below is a screenshot:
[image: Screenshot of detected FTDI chip]
Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

please check the permissions of the /dev node

```
$ls -la /dev/ttyUSB0
```

There is a high chance it shall resemble

```
crw-rw----. 1 root dialout 188, 0 Jul 18 13:27 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

A character device with RW permissions for ROOT and RW permissions for dialout group.

If this is the case check the group membership of the user attempting to access

```
$ groups
```

if the user is not part of the dialout group, add them

```
$ sudo usermod -a -G dialout $username
```

The user then needs to logout and log back into reload the group permissions

Comment: This was great! I ran `who -u`. Got the PID, then `sudo kill PID`. 
It totally worked! I was missing the last important point, **logout**. 
Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Your new serial port is /dev/ttyUSB0 (and ttyUSB1, like you show above).

Since it appears that you are having trouble accessing it with 'screen', I would suggest that you look at the permissions of /dev/ttyUSB0 (and/or ttyUSB1).

***Sometimes one needs to change the permission to allow others (other than root) to access the tty ports.***

as root:
*chmod ugo+wr /dev/ttyUSB0*

(This change may be reset when you reboot.  That can be fixed with a little googling.)

What do you see when you do "*ls -l /dev/ttyUSB**" in a terminal?

Also:
With putty in linux, one would specify /dev/ttyUSB0 as the port (not COM1, etc.)

Comment: please don't change the permissions that way... udev generates nodes on-demand THUS at the next reboot said permissions are lost. udev.rules file is the better way to manage such permissions. Equally this WIDE permissions is a windows approach and not UNIX... the correct thing is to confirm the group and there is a high chance such a node is created as part of the SERIAL or DIALOUT group, thus the correct method would be to add the user to the SERIAL/DIALOUT permissions group

Comment: The output of `ls -l /dev/ttyUSB0` is:
`crw-rw-rw- 1 root dialout 188, 0 jul 18 14:18 /dev/ttyUSB0`
and same for /dev/ttyUSB1

I have added the user to the dialout group too, by these commands:
'sudo gpasswd -add amitabhydv dialout'
checked with, `groups amitabhydv` and got:
`amitabhydv : amitabhydv adm dialout cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare`
Tried. Still nothing.

Comment: if you have just added the user to that group you need to logout for the groups to be reloaded

Comment: @JonRB  (Re: permissions) I totally agree, once you know what works, and why it's broken.

Comment: @ChrisKnudsen thought you would, this was more of a note for people that find this in future.

Comment: Thanks @Chris, it works now. I was missing the **logout** step. :)